# How to efficiently retrieve top 20 referenced values of a Mysql table alongside PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `object` table in which I am storing data associated with objects that are recognized in photos. This means that I could have multiple rows per photo.

Example of `object` table displaying 3 objects recognized in 1 photo.

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| id | name   | photoId | companyId |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1  | Person | 33      | 50        |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| 2  | Cat    | 33      | 50        |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| 3  | Dog    | 33      | 50        |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Eventually, this table could grow to be huge. If 500,000 photos are uploaded and 20 objects are recognized in each, that's 10,000,000 rows.

**Questions**

- Should I worry about the number of potential rows within this table?
- Is there a way that I can efficiently query this table by `object.companyId` in order to provide myself with a list of the top 5 objects that have been recognized for each company? I have an attempt shown below but it already seems sluggish with the minimal data I have stored.

**My attempt:**

Retrieve results from MySql:

`select * from object where companyId=50`

Iterate results within PHP to get count per label:

```
foreach($res as $row){
    //get how many times this label shows up in the results
    $labelCnt                     =  array_count_values(array_column($res, 'name'))[$row['name']];
    //create an array of all label counts (label -> cnt)
    $allLabelCntArr[$row['name']] = $labelCnt;
}
arsort($allLabelCnts); //sort from highest to lowest
$topFive = array_slice($allLabelCnts, 0, 5, true); //get top 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the top 5 objects for a given company directly in your MySQL query:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM object
WHERE companyId = 50
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This will return the 5 rows (or as many as you put in the `LIMIT` clause) with the highest count of the `name` values. As long as you have indexes on `name` and `companyId` this query should perform well regardless of table size.

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c39b8b/1)